# Maths controversies due to an empty universe?

Tags: math-history

In France, most math/CS grad students hear the following story:

> On the day of his defense, Jay, a PhD candidate in pure Maths, presents his results, a series of highly non-trivial theorems which brilliantly establish universal properties for objects of a set $\cal B$, defined as the subset of $\cal A$ satisfying an additional property $P$. Both the characterization of $\cal A$ and the definition of $P$ are quite non-trivial, and belong to different subfields of maths (e.g., topology and number-theory). After acknowledging the originality and technicity of the proofs, the jury moves on to the questions, and ask:
>
> > Could you give us an example of an object in $\cal B$?
>
> Jay starts building the object on the board, fails, try again, fails again and the defense moves on to avoid any further embarassment (at that moment, Jay is silently weeping in a corner of the room).
>
> Unfortunately, during the following deliberation, the jury manages to show a contradiction in the axioms defining $\cal A$ and $P$! All the theorems were legit, as they all started with universal quantifications ($\forall x\in {\cal B}$...). Jay does not get his PhD, and moves on to make buckets of money doing applied maths for the finance industry (happy end version).

Now, I suspect this story is a urban legend, as I already heard two distinct versions of it (please comment with your local variant if you have one), but I was wondering if there were instances of controversies in the history of Mathematics that may have resulted from a similar situation. The key ingredients in this story are:

- Set $\cal A$ and property $P$ such that ${\cal B} := \{x\in {\cal A}\mid P(x)\}=\varnothing$ non-trivially (think "[Millenium prize](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Millennium_Prize_Problems) non-trivial");
- A second property $P'$;
- Instances of ${\cal B}$ being difficult to construct or handle in a human lifetime (e.g. in number theory);
- A first result by author X, showing that $ P'(x), \forall x \in B$, using somewhat obscure techniques.
- A second result by author Y, showing that $\neg P'(x), \forall x \in B$, using even obscurer techniques.
- An undignified academic squabble involving X and Y (+ their respective proponents) pointing out typos and mistakes in the respective proofs.
- Once the war is over, both sides reluctantly accept the other's result, or simply lose interest (and forget to collect the 1M prize for settling the ${\cal B} =\varnothing$ question).

Is anyone aware of any instance of such a scenario in the history of Maths?
If not, how did communities (note that several communities may be simultaneously involved in this game) manage to prevent such a situation to occur?

Edit: As funny as they may be, this question is *not* about "epic failures" of grad students (or about trivial/useless results in Maths), rather about the history/sociology of Mathematics.

Comment: I don't know any public controversies in the past few decades that began in a dissertation defense. Plenty of ugly battles over priority, validity of long articles/preprints, and so on, but mostly established people. The two in progress now, prime gaps and ABC, have managed to stay even-tempered so far.

Comment: Note that the emphasis should neither be on the student story (just an intro, and most likely a hoax crafted by insecure grads) nor on the 'academic squabble', but rather on the fact that seemingly contradictory results can be established on a non-trivially empty universe.

Comment: Your comment got cut off. If the emptiness idea is the main thing, there is the story of a dissertation on Holder functions with exponent larger than one, lots of conclusions. But such functions are actually constant.

Comment: @WillJagy I must hear that story.

Comment: @Arkamis, that is all I know, Shiing Tung Yau told it in the 1980's. The Holder condition can be generalized to manifolds. Yau had no names to offer, so it may also be urban legend. It is easy to show that Holder exponent above 1 means differentiable with gradient 0, therefore constant.   http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/H%C3%B6lder_condition

Comment: Is that a true story?  Also, in the controversy version, the correctness of both results should be extremely hard to ascertain by a single individual ( eg if they borrow to different subfields of maths). I'm asking for instances, but I firmly believe these situations are catastrophe waiting to happen...

Comment: @YannPonty, I noticed that you are currently @ SFU. Maybe you could chat with Dr. Archibald who teaches math history course.

Comment: In the event that $\mathsf{P}\stackrel?=\mathsf{NP}$ is eventually answered in the affirmative, a vast literature exploring the space in between will suddenly become obsolete.

Comment: The grad student story actually has a true counterpart at the opposite extreme: the topological property characterized in [this paper](http://projecteuclid.org/euclid.pja/1195521427) is possessed by all topological spaces.

Comment: The ${\sf P}$ vs ${\sf NP}$ question is extremely relevant. However, to be completely "on target" it would be great if it were settled by the independent derivations of (valid!) contradictory results in the "in between" area.

Comment: @BrianM.Scott Do you know if the authors were aware (perhaps later) of this?

Comment: @MatemáticosChibchas: I’m reasonably sure that they didn’t realize it when they introduced the concept and wrote the paper. I don’t know whether they learned of it later.

Answer (score 4):

The canonical example is probably the reluctance of the Pythagoreans to accept the existence of irrational numbers.

The story goes that when a student named Hippasus presented his defense of the irrationality of $\sqrt{2}$, his advisory committee listened carefully, conferred with the gods, and subsequently had him drowned at sea in an apparent show of disapproval.

By contrast, graduate school today is much more civil. They merely drown your soul and financial future.

Comment: Great story!
However, as much as I sympathize with grad students (been there not so long ago, and "permanent grad" would actually fit my current job description), the question is not so much about their fate as it is about the potential for controversies/discoveries while working on empty sets.

Comment: "(...)drown your soul and financial future." Hmmm, put this way, drowning of your body seems a reasonable alternative.